# unable to close opened excel workbook

Tags: vba, excel

I am building a excel file with commandbuttons, userforms etc. that contain links to other workbooks.

For the commandbuttons on my sheet I use the same code as for the commandbuttons in my userforms:

```
workbooks.open "path"
```

with the userform commandbuttons ater this the following is added

```
unload me
```

When I open a workbook via a userform I am unable to close it afterwards. I must activate my workbook first, then activate the opened one and then can I close it

I have tried putting "unload me" befor and after the "workbooks.open" but this doesn't change anything.

I also tried the followin, also didn't work:

```
unload me
dim wb as workbook
set wb = workbooks.open"pathname"
wb.activate
```

anyone any ideas?

Example of how it is now:
Someone needs to make a price calculation. they open the prices userform in my file. they click on the button "calculationfile". The calculationfile opens. they make there calculation and now they are finished in the calculationfile. So they want to close it by clicking on the cross. But they can't click the cross. then they switch to my file on the taskbar and then switch back to the calculation file. now they are able of clicking the cross

I dont understand why they can't click it the first time but they can click it after switching between mine and the openend workbook.

Comment: I don't see any code where you try and close a workbook here......

Comment: I am talking about closing through clicking the cross. I am opening workbooks with information and after someone has seen the information they need they want to close the workbook again. however with my code you need to switch between workbooks before you can click on the cross

Comment: I have no idea what would cause this, but you know that `workbooks.Open` method sets a new *active* workbook, so your `wb.Activate` statement isn't doing anything extra. Insert `ThisWorkbook.Activate` right before the `wb.Activate` and see if that hacks the solution.

Comment: Also not working. What I also find strange is when i open a file directly by clicking on an button on the sheet i don't have this problem. when i open a  file by clicking a userformbutton i get this malfunction.

Comment: I think the `Unload` statement should come *after* the others, though that may nto solve the problem it is probably best to do it that way. Are you able to do `workbooks.close("file")` via the VBA code? Or does that present any error or failure?  If so, that might provide a clue to the root cause of your problem.

Comment: @DavidZemens I tried to close it in my code and that indeed provides an error. See : http://imgur.com/a/bQoLQ

Comment: @Mick17 `Workbooks.Close` takes *only* the filename, not the full *path+filename*. If you provide the paht+filename, that error is expected.

Comment: @DavidZemens changed it, it works without an error. no matter where i put "unload me"

Comment: I'll add that as an "answer"

Answer (score 2):

I suspect this is due to improper form handling and the "default instance" recreating itself after you unload it.  If you don't create your own instance of the form before you show it, VBA will do all kinds of squirrelly things when you use it after it's unloaded.

If all you need to do is open a workbook and unload the form, *don't increment the workbook's reference count before you unload the form.  Also, don't attempt to run any other code after you call `Unload Me` from the form.  The code you posted should simply be:

```
Workbooks.Open "pathname"
Unload Me
```

Of course the calling code for the form isn't in the question, but it can likely be solved there as well.

Comment: Thank you for the information I will see if I can work with this. The calling code is simply:  userform1.show

Answer (score 0):

`Unload` only affects a `UserForm`.

Try adding a reference to the open workbook and then closing it like so:

```
dim wb as Workbook
set wb = Workbooks.Open "pathname"
wb.activate
' do whatever with it while it's open
wb.Close
```

If whatever you are doing is not automated, you will need a button on your form that will set the reference to the workbook and close it once the user has completed editing.

Comment: Than you for your help, but I think my question isn't clear enough. I don't want to change anything in the workbooks that I open. We work with a lot of different excel files that are all on different locations. I am creating one excel file with which you can open the files you actually need. See it as a "linking" file. If i open a workbook via my workbook I need to switch between my workbook and the opened one before I can close the opened one by clicking the cross

Comment: So you want to click a button to open a workbook, then hide the userform and show the newly opened workbook?  And on the user manually closing the workbook, you want the userform to reappear or something?

Comment: For example: someone needs the file to calculate a price. they open the prices userform in my file. They click on the button "calculationfile". The calculationfile opens. they do there calculation and now they are finished in this file. They want to close this file again by clicking the cross, but now they can't click the cross. they need to switch to my file, switch back to the calculation file and now they are able to click the cross.    I don't understand why they cant click it the first time but they can click it after they switched between workbooks

Answer (score 0):

If you define the workbooks that you open as a variable - you will be able to close them easily. Keep in mind this does not save the workbook.

```
Dim DataBook As Workbook
Set DataBook = Workbooks.open ("pathname")
' Do something useful with the file

DataBook.Close
```

Comment: Than you for your help, but I think my question isn't clear enough. I don't want to change anything in the workbooks that I open. We work with a lot of different excel files that are all on different locations. I am creating one excel file with which you can open the files you actually need. See it as a "linking" file. If i open a workbook via my workbook I need to switch between my workbook and the opened one before I can close the opened one by clicking the cross

Answer (score 0):

It is not completely clear what you are trying to ask here, but I'll give it my best in providing you a full answer. If you are having no success with the `Unload Me` statement when it comes to closing a **user form**, try specifying the full form name in VBA. That is:

```
Unload UserFormName
```

If you are trying to close the **workbook** you have opened (via the user form), you can use the `Workbooks.Close` method:

```
Dim wb as Workbook
Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:="C:\example.xls") 
wb.Activate
'Close workbook
wb.Close
'Unload form
Unload ExampleForm
```

More on the use of the Unload statement can be found here:- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa445829(v=vs.60).aspx

And more on the use of the Workbooks.Close statement can be found here:- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838613.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what's causing the behavior you describe (inability to click the "Close" X button in the active Excel window). However your current workflow is:

1. User interacts with form to review/access a file
2. User clicks a button on the form which unloads the form
3. User is then expected to manually close out of the file opened in (1)

A better solution would be to remove the third step, and close the workbook from one of the form's event-handlers (`UserForm_QueryClose` or `UserForm_Terminate`). Alternatively you could add this to a `CommandButton`'s `Click` event, but that's not very different than requiring the user to manually close the file.

This could be as simple as:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Terminate()
' should be called when form Unloads
On Error Resume Next
Workbooks.Close "filename.xlsx"
End Sub
```

In this manner, the file will be closed any time the user closes or otherwise unloads the userform.

Answer (score 0):

OK I think I found a way around it.

Let's say I have a workbook1 which has a form called ControlPage with command button that opens up workbook2.

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

```
Dim workbook2 As Workbook
Dim workbook1name As String
workbook1name = ThisWorkbook.name

Set workbook2 = Workbooks.Open("workbook2.xlsx")
ControlPage.Hide
Workbooks(workbook1name).Activate
Workbooks("workbook2.xlsx").Activate

End Sub
```

So basically because 'activate' bit doesn't seem to work properly when I try to activate workbook 2 straight away, I just activate the first, and then the second one ane after another. Twisted but did the trick for me.